# Determine what implementationt to use in C# during run time

Tags: c#

My code talks to 4 different machines (money machines from different companies). Each one of them does:
1. Dispense
2. Deposit

let's call the machines(A,B,C,D).

In my code if I want to call Deposit from a machine I would end up with something like:

```
MyProject.A.Deposit()
```

I ended up with switch statements that are basically something like this:

```
Switch(machine){
case A:
     MyProject.A.Deposit();
 break;

 case B:
     MyProject.B.Deposit();
 break;
}
```

The bigger the code gets,the problem of very long namespaces and switch statements becomes annoying.

My question is:

Is there a way I can tell the compiler to use the specific namespace during the run-time? Or Maybe by using a config variable or a string that has namespace path.

I wanted something where I can do:

```
Deposit();
```

Since i have the information of which machine I am connected to, the problem is just how to change dynamically the namespace.

Comment: @Muhannad I have an answer for you but can't post because the question is _on hold_ and SO is stupid. Anyway, I posted [a gist with my answer](https://gist.github.com/pedroreys/d736515ebf388862fbbc326056df574e)

Comment: @Pedro it's reopened

Comment: thanks @YvetteColomb!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming all four machines' `Dispense` and `Deposit` methods share the same contract, all you need is to create an *interface* that they all implement:

```
public interface IMachine
{
    void Dispense();
    void Deposit();
}
```

Then make sure you implement this same interface on all your machine concrete implementations:

```
public class MachineA : IMachine
{
     public void Dispense()
     {
         // do something here
     }

     public void Deposit()
     {
         // do something here
     }
}

public class MachineB : IMachine
{
     public void Dispense()
     {
         // do something here
     }

     public void Deposit()
     {
         // do something here
     }
}

public class MachineC : IMachine
{
     public void Dispense()
     {
         // do something here
     }

     public void Deposit()
     {
         // do something here
     }
}

public class MachineD : IMachine
{
     public void Dispense()
     {
         // do something here
     }

     public void Deposit()
     {
         // do something here
     }
}
```

I'm assuming you don't use Dependency Injection or have an IoC container currently in your system, so to keep things simple you can have a *Factory* to always create the `IMachine` instances for you:

```
public static class MachineFactory
{
     // this is assuming you are reading the machine name from AppConfig
     private static Lazy<string> _machineName = new Lazy<string>(() => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TargetMachine"]);

     public IMachine GetMachine()
     {
          switch(_machineName.Value)
          {
               case "MachineA":
                    return new MachineA();                    
               case "MachineB":
                    return new MachineB();
               case "MachineC":
                    return new MachineC();
               case "MachineD":
                    return new MachineD();

          }
     }
}
```

Now, in the rest of your application, whenever you need an instance of a machine, all you need to do is use the factory without having to worry about the different machine implementations:

```
var machine = MachineFactory.GetMachine();
```

Comment: I like this way so much thank you for that. Out of curiosity, I am still wondering if there's a way other than interfaces to dynamically redirect the compiler to the right class. Something like the files system in an OS where you can provide the path.

Answer (score -1):

You could go through a switch-case for the value that will decide the namespace,  where you have "using NamespaceX;" inside the cases.

Comment: This wouldn't work at run-time.. I would suggest you to try the solutions you propose before posting them

Comment: currently I am having something like this that's why hate it I feel like there should be a better way I just can't figure it out :(